# Remove spaces in array element and add empty element in that place

Tags: java, arrays

Lets say I have an array like this:

```
[4s3hk7uf4vvjhmqt3u946f0n1r,2,3,asadasdasd,    wew wewe]
```

I wish to remove the spaces if there in any element in the array and add a empty element in that place. In our case since we have two space before

```
   wew wewe
```

the array should transform to :

```
 [4s3hk7uf4vvjhmqt3u946f0n1r,2,3,asadasdasd,,,wew wewe]
```

Are there any way for this to be done?

Comment: That's definitely not java code. Are you talking about JavaScript? Anyway, there sould be quotes if those are Strings inside the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this:

```
List<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>();
for( String s : yourArray ){
  while( s.startsWith( " " ) ){
    newList.add( "" );
    s = s.substring( 1 );
  }

  int indexToAddValue = newList.size();

  while( s.endsWith( " " ) ){
    newList.add( "" );
    s = s.substring( 0, s.length() - 1 );
  }

  newList.add( indexToAddValue, s );
 }
 String[] newArray = newList.toArray( String[] );
```

Comment: its adding elements twice.

Comment: just tested it with array `[ "aa", "  b", "c  ", " d " ]` and this is the output: `[aa, |, |, b, c, |, |, |, d, |]` (I replaced the spaces with | for better readability)